# SELECT INTO Multiple Variable in MySQL declaration

Tags: mysql, variables

Is that possible to set two parameters value in single query in Stored Procedure Mysql?
I want , two different parameters as output , i don't want to con-cat it.

```
Declare v_first_name varchar(100);
Declare v_last_name Varchar(100);

SET p_email_id = 'some_email_id';

/* 
instead of this i want to laod result in single query   
Set v_first_name=(Select first_name From user_master Where email_id=p_email_id);
Set v_last_name=(Select last_name From user_master Where email_id=p_email_id);

*/

if flag1=1 then 
Select 1 As 'Result',v_first_name As 'first_name',v_last_name As 'last_name';  
else    
Select 0 As 'Result',v_first_name As 'first_name',v_last_name  As 'last_name';
End if;
```

Any help ?

```
select first_name INTO @v_first_name , last_name INTO @v_last_name From user_master Where email_id=p_email_id; ==== **Not Working**
```

Answer (score 11):

Just list them out with commas after the `INTO`:

```
SELECT a, b, c
INTO v_a, v_b, v_C
FROM ...
```

Comment: Hi @siride. How can get these value in next select query like (SELECt id, name, v_a as value1, v_b as value2 FROM table WHERE id =1)

Comment: @Kailas: I don't understand the question. Your example SELECT is exactly how you'd get them out.

Comment: why is this not working inside a concat query in stored procedure?

Comment: @Fakipo Did you declare the variables first? I'd ask in a new question first.

Comment: No, it works. we just have to use user defined variables..